# Error: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search").click()
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys("RETURN")
```

This is my code that is meant search test on youtube however when I run it youtube opens and I get an error saying "DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object."
My chromedriver is in the same folder as my python file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should fix your problem:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ser = Service("./chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search").click()
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys("RETURN")
```